# Windows spreadsheet program that can handle 10 million rows

Tags: windows, spreadsheet

I have a data file with 14 columns and 9,523,125 rows.

What Windows desktop spreadsheet program (NOT A DATABASE!) can handle at least 9,523,125 rows?

I need to view the data, and sort by columns.

Preferably gratis.

Answer (score 3):

If you must you could give [pySpread](http://manns.github.io/pyspread/index.html) a go - it can handle up to 80 000 000 rows subject to possible memory limitations.

Alternatively you could look at [Python](http://www.python.org) + [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - the combination is very good for dealing with large data sets.

All the above are free and cross platform, just not online.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PowerPivot](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/power-pivot-help-HA104220543.aspx):

- non-free
- Microsoft Excel 2010/2013 add-in
- [up to 2 billion rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413465(v=sql.110).aspx)

[image]

Comment: But it's not online...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Delimit](http://www.delimitware.com/):

- offline and non-free (50 USD)
- 64-bit Windows 8.1, 8, or 7
- Open data files up to 2 billion rows and 2 million columns large
- Open large delimited data files; 100's of MBs or GBs in size

[image]

More features:

> - Quickly open any delimited data file.
> - Edit any cell.
> - Easily convert files from one delimiter to another like
> - CSV to TAB.
> - Split-up any delimited file into file parts of equal size.
> - Join multiple delimited files into one resulting file.
> - Quickly select which columns to extract and in which order.
> - Extract data from any delimited file by specifying the columns,
> - rows and/or filter to apply.
> - Sort any delimited data file based on cell content.
> - Remove duplicate rows based on user specified columns.
> - Bookmark any cell for quick subsequent access.
> - Open large delimited data files; 100's of MBs or GBs in size!
> - Open data files up to 2 billion rows and 2 million columns large!
> - Work with: character delimited, string delimited, fixed column width or just plain text files.
> - Quickly see all your bookmarks, double-click to jump to any of them or click to rename.
> - Keep track of long running operations.
> - Keep track of the current selection.
> - Scroll to any part of the file or split the view into multiple panes.
> - Freeze the 1st row of any file.
> - Open multiple files and quickly switch between them.
> - Configure built-in and custom file delimitation rules for automatic parsing of files.

Answer (score 1):

[CSV Explorer](https://www.CSVExplorer.com) is an online tool, not free, that can open spreadsheets and CSVs with millions of rows. You can search, aggregate, filter, plot, etc. without writing any code.

https://www.CSVExplorer.com

Comment: Would you mind moving this answer to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53211/online-spreadsheet-program-that-can-view-10-million-rows ? I have split into two questions. Thanks and sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Excel **2007** and up can already handle [1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=Office_2007)

[WPS Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPS_Office) (formerly Kingsoft Office) Spreadsheets has the [same limits](https://www.wps.com/en-US/spreadsheets?lang=en). [LibreOffice Calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Calc) also supports the same number of rows since [LibreOffice 3.3](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2011/01/the-document-foundation-announces-first-release-of-libreoffice/). OpenOffice supports [1048576 x 1024](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Miscellaneous/What%27s_the_maximum_number_of_rows_and_cells_for_a_spreadsheet_file%3F) sheets. And they're all free