# Online spreadsheet webapp that can view 10 million rows

Tags: web-apps, csv, spreadsheet

I have a data file with 14 columns and 9,523,125 rows.

What online spreadsheet program (NOT A DATABASE!) can view at least 9,523,125 rows?

I must be able to:

- upload the CSV file
- view it (with some kind of paging I guess)
- sort by a column

... just with a web browser (no browser add-on).

Preferably gratis. Either as a service or self-hosted.

Answer (score 1):

One option which could be in a browser or in a command window/terminal is the combination of [Python](https://www.python.org/), [ipython](https://ipython.org/) & [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) *plus for in a browser [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/)* - however it does not look much like a spreadsheet. I suspect that this would not be too much of a problem as few people have the time or inclination to read 9 million rows and would be looking at slices of such data or creating summaries such as min, max, mean, sd, etc.

Just to prove the point a generated a .csv file with 10,000,000 rows x 15 columns, (the first column a sequential number, the second a random integer in the range 1..5000000 and the rest "abcdef" and took some measurements with a final blank column due to me ending each line with a comma. I am running on a laptop running Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] under Win10/64.

ipython command prompt times:

```
%time df = pandas.read_csv('big.csv')
Wall time: 25.3 s
%time df = df.sort_values('Col_0') # This is the random number column
Wall time: 19 s
%time df['Col_0'].mean() 
Wall time: 183 ms
 2499787.4277122
%time df['Col_0'].std()
Wall time: 364 ms
 1443592.9048092277
```

Of course with Jupyter notebooks we can do the same sort of thing in a browser:
[image: the above under Jupyter]

Pandas will allow you to perform most of the likely manipulations on such a large data set including basic plotting and with the addition of one of the many charting libraries you can produce fancy graphs, etc.

Note that Jupyter & Pandas can be run as a self hosting solution or via a service such as mybinder.org or colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb or hosted on AWS or similar.

Answer (score 0):

[CSV Explorer](https://CSVExplorer.com) is an online tool to open big CSV files and spreadsheets with millions of rows. You can search, sort, and filter in a few clicks.

https://www.CSVExplorer.com

Comment: Please include the price and a screenshot, thanks!